# Should CreatedBy contain only user id if User model is an aggregate root itself?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I have just started a project to learn more about DDD.
This can be a stupid question but just wanted to learn more about DDD.

For example, if I have 2 domain model here, Product and User, **both are aggregate root**. In Product, I have other states/ properties and 2 states called "CreatedBy" and "CreatedDate", which let's say the domain expert tell me that **both "CreatedBy and Date" is part of the business domain**. The createdby have to be related to User model. I was thinking about 3 options, not sure if which of them is correct.

1. CreatedBy only contain ID of User. (`public int CreatedBy ...`)
2. CreatedBy is a User object. (`public User CreatedBy ...`)
3. Create a value object call MetaData as below

   ```
   class MetaData 
   { 
        public int CreatedBy ...
        public string CreatorName ...
        public string CreatorStatus ...
        public DateTime CreatedDate ...
   }
   ```

When creating/ saving a product,

- For option 1, I will only need to get UserID of current user and set
  to my product model
- For option 2, I will get UserID of current user    and call User
  repository to get this user and set to my product model
- For option    3, I will get UserID of current user, construct the
  MetaData    object and set to my product model.

I am not sure which method is correct and hopefully my understanding about DDD is correct until now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Product` and `User` have a **domain relationship** namely: "a product is (always?) created by an user" . This can be **implemented** by making the Product reference the User and the simplest method is for a Product to have the UserId.

Aggregates shouldn't overlap, they are autonomous, that's why you're using only the UserId instead of the whole User. If you need to combine different aggregates then that's a hint there's a 3rd one lurking around but you can't see it yet.

Comment: If in case I need to display creator details alongside with product details, I will use a application service to call both product and user repository and map them into a so called, ViewModel/ DTO?

Comment: You can query directly the db. Usually we use CQRS with DDD so we already have a queryable read model.